# How to Copy Text to Clip Board in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

simple question:
How to Copy Text to Clip Board in Compose?

before Compose we used to do something like this:

```kotlin
val clipboardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText(
    content_et.getText().toString()
)
clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)
Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, R.string.copied_to_clipboard, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

what we should do in compose?

Comment: You can set and get text using `LocalClipboardManager.`  `clipboardManager.setText(AnnotatedString((text)))` does the job

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
val clipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
clipboardManager.setText(AnnotatedString("Some text"))
```